# Is there a technique to knocking down doors?

Tags: xbox-360, dead-island

In Dead Island, there is an achievement called [Knock, Knock](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/942713-dead-island/cheats) which is completed by breaching a locked door on the first attempt.

[image: dead island door minigame]

The meter in the game is incomprehensible to me and I've never been able to open a door in under three blows. **Is there some technique that is more effective for knocking down doors?**

Comment: It should be noted that Sam B. has an ability in his 2nd skill tree (combat/offense) that allows him to charge through locked doors, bypassing the meter-minigame completely. That being said, I'm not sure if that gets you the achievement or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you enter the door-knocking minigame, you're presented with a grayish bar with a red center. Furthermore, there's a white indicator that starts in the middle. When you hold your right joystick down (or move your mouse back), the white indicator starts swinging from end to end. By swinging the mouse or joysytick forward/up, you slam into the door. The closer your white indicator is to the center, the more damage you do to the door, indicated by the grey bar reducing. In order to knock down the door in one attempt, you must swing forward when the white indicator is in the dead center of the bar.

Note that, to make this easier, you don't have to swing forward on the first pass. As long as you keep your mouse where you moved it back or your joystick down, the indicator will keep swinging. Rushing it will usually only cause you to mess up.

Comment: I would like to add that you need to move the mouse up at a certain speed aswell, sometimes i hit it right dead in the center and it still takes me a 2 hits to get through. I think it's because i don't follow through with my upper mouse movementwise.

Comment: You don't have to continue to move the mouse. Just flick it up once, wait, flick down once at the appropriate time. (If you are like me and have Y inverted, you flick the mouse `forward` or `up` to get the line moving, then flick downwards to stop it.)

Comment: @horatio I know. Hold was the wrong choice of word.